# UWP map update performance

Tags: dictionary, uwp, uwp-xaml

UWP map control has outstanding performance - I can draw thousands of polygons on the map, and it stays responsive while zooming and panning.

However, if I update position of items on the map, very quickly it becomes unresponsive. From my benchmark I am  only able to achieve about 100 updates per second, so if I try to update position of 100 objects 1'se per second, that's it.

Each update does not replace the map element, but only changes it's position property. 
Also each update is a separate method call. 
Is there some kind of trick or technique to achieving good update performance? Given how well it performs on "static" content, there must be a better way to use it.

Comment: For “static contents”, the position of the thousands of polygons are calculated once and then the polygons are re-rendered once; For your benchmark, following each call the UI needs to be re-rendered, so this is the difference: the bottle neck here is the I/O (rendering), not calculating float point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Static content is much easier to render, as it can be cached and the map can then render it very quickly. 100 updates a second is above 60 FPS most games have and that is quite a bit taxing on the performance, especially in this case, where the map wasn't built for such purpose.

In a previous project we instead used [Win2D framework for UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) to render objects above the map. Win2D is well suited to manage 60 FPS rendering and is quite efficient, so you might find it advantageous.

Comment: Sorry I realise now the question was unclear: I can update position 100 times per second. If I have more that one hundred objects, I am stuck with sub second update speed

Comment: I probably need further clarification, as in such case my answer still holds. Doing any position update means the object must be re-rendered, which causes the performance issue you are seeing. Map objects are great for static data, but frequent updates will not hold that well.